# Extracting numbers in 9+.9* format from text with Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I want to match decimals with integer parts but with or without decimal parts, e.g. `1.1`, `0.1`, `1.` but not `.1` in Scala.

Currently, my solution is

```
val pattern: Regex = raw"\d+.\d*".r;
```

However, it wrongly matches the decimal ".2000". `pattern.findAllIn(".2000").toList(0)` would equal to 2000. What's wrong?

Comment: You may use `val pattern: Regex = """\d+\.?\d*""".r`

Comment: Regex for decimal numbers... Is there really no duplicate for that?

Comment: Not exactly what you need but https://regexone.com/problem/matching_decimal_numbers

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The regex in the accepted answer matches `.456`, and probably doesn't match `1.`. I'm not sure whether OP wants to match numbers without a period, your proposal seems to be able to skip the `\.` because of `?`. But the important part is the `\.` instead of just `.`, so maybe you could adjust your comment by removing `?` and post this as an answer? Unfortunately, even a canonical duplicate wouldn't help much in this particular case, because of the strange requirement of numbers ending with period.

Comment: What is the difference between key word raw and """ """?

Comment: @lucasinny You may use both if that works for you. Inside a triple-quoted string literal, you may use single backslashes as regex escapes (i.e. a single backslash symbol actually defines a literal backslash), so it is handy.

Answer (score 1):

An unescaped dot matches any chsar but a newline char.

In the most basic form, the regex to extract numbers that conform to the `9+.9*` format will look like

```
val pattern: Regex = """\d+\.\d*""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlWXDU/1). Here, `\d+` matches 1+ digits, `\.` matches a single dot and `\d*` matches 0 or more digits.

In case you want to avoid matching `192.168` in `192.168.0.2`, add some lookarounds, e.g.

```
val pattern: Regex = """(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d*(?!\.?\d)""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlWXDU/2). Here, the `(?<!\d\.)` negative lookbehind disallows a digit and a dot to appear right before the number in the desired format, and the `(?!\.?\d)` negative lookahead forbids a `.` + digit or just a digit right after the number.